# How to release Android system player or force certain app to play music?

Tags: java, android

In my app, there are three functions for three buttons, I will press these button one by one.

Button A, launch first player and start play music

Button B, stop playing music

Button C, launch another player and start play music

After I pressed the Button C, the phone still play the music in first player

How can I release Android system player from first player?

Or force certain app to hold the system player?

```
//Button A, launch first player and start play music
public void functionA(){
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.maxmpz.audioplayer");
    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(launchIntent);


    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int keyCode=KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE;

    try {
        long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - 1+1000;
        KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode, 0);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);
        eventtime++;
        eventtime+=1000;
        KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode, 0);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}

//Button B, stop playing music
public void functionB(){
    try {
        long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - 1;
        KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode, 0);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);
        eventtime++;
        KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode, 0);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}

//Button C, launch another player and start play music
public void functionC(){
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.foobar2000.foobar2000");
    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(launchIntent);


    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int keyCode=KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE;

    try {
        long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - 1+1000;
        KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode, 0);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(downEvent);
        eventtime++;
        eventtime+=1000;
        KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode, 0);
        am.dispatchMediaKeyEvent(upEvent);
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try out `AudioFocus`?

Comment: How can I use `AudioFocus`?  This music is not playing in my app, I just call other player to play music.